# gwt pushbutton works in IE not firefox chrome

Tags: gwt, button, imagebutton

using GWT, I have a PushButton (with an image) contained in a FlowPanel in turn contained in a DockPanel WEST component. The button responds to clicks only in IE but not in Firefox, Chrome. Any help appreciated...

Code:

```
DockPanel dock = new DockPanel(); 
FlowPanel navigation = new FlowPanel(); 
PushButton synopsisButton = new PushButton(synopsis); 
navigation.add(synopsisButton); 
dock.add(navigation,dock.WEST); 
RootPanel.get().add(dock);

synopsisButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() { 
  @Override 
  public void onClick(ClickEvent e) { 
    Window.alert("in synopsis click handler");
});
```

Comment: my code:  DockPanel dock = new DockPanel();  FlowPanel navigation = new FlowPanel(); PushButton synopsisButton = new PushButton(synopsis); navigation.add(synopsisButton); dock.add(navigation,dock.WEST); RootPanel.get().add(dock);

Comment: ALSO: synopsisButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(ClickEvent e) {
          Window.alert("in synopsis click handler"); AND THIS ALERT SEEN ONLY ON IE.....

Comment: Make sure your GWT app is working in standards mode. That means using Layout panels, such as DockLayoutPanel instead of DockPanel. Read this bit of doc for more info: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards

Answer (score 3):

> The GWT 2.0 layout system is intended to work only in "standards
>   mode". This means that you should always place the following
>   declaration at the top of your HTML pages:
>
> As mentioned above, some of the existing GWT panels do not behave
>   entirely as expected in standards mode. This stems primarily from
>   differences between the way standards and quirks modes render tables.
>
> CellPanel (HorizontalPanel, VerticalPanel, DockPanel) - these panels
>   all use table cells as their basic structural units. While they still
>   work in standards mode, they will lay out their children somewhat
>   differently. The main difference is that their children will not
>   respect width and height properties (it is common to set children of
>   CellPanels explicitly to 100% width and height). There are also
>   differences in the way that the browser allocates space to individual
>   table rows and columns that can lead to unexpected behavior in
>   standards mode.
>
> You should use DockLayoutPanel in place of DockPanel. VerticalPanel
>   can usually be replaced by a simple FlowPanel (since block-level
>   elements will naturally stack up vertically).
>   http://code.google.com/intl/ru-RU/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiPanels.html#Standards

Check your .html file in "war" folder in your project. It should contain `<!doctype html>`. 
I tested your code and it works well in all browsers.